# Why does it take maximum of $n/\log n$ digits to represent the number $2^n - 1$ in base of $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity

Given the number $n$. Why does it take maximum of $\frac{n}{\log n}$ digits to represent the number $2^n - 1$ in base of $n$?

Comment: Why is this listed as complex analysis?

Comment: Because it is a part of a complexity algorithm called Radix-Sort

Comment: Complexity is not the same as complex analysis, which is analysis on the complex plane.

Comment: Changed the tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  to express any number $m$ in base $n$ takes $\lfloor \log_n m \rfloor +1$ digits.  To see this, think about base $10$.  With one digit you can express any number up to $9$, for which the floor of the log is $0$.  With three digits you can express numbers up to $999$, for which the floor is $2$.  What base of logs were you planning to use?

Comment: Helped a lot! Thanks Ross!